# react-zoom-pan-pinch React weird behaviour with HTML structure

Tags: reactjs, zooming, pinchzoom

I'm using the react-zoom-pan-pinch library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) to enable zoomIn and zoomOut on an html structure contained by rows and items
[This is an image from the app and its' structure, each pixel is an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMEYt.jpg).
[When I zoomIn and zoomOut the effect made is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t08Ti.jpg)
making the bottom of the component unreachable (I cannot "scroll" it down as it returns to the possition on image)

My code is as follows....

JSX:

```
return (
      <div className="artContainer">
        <TransformWrapper
                initialScale={0.5}
                initialPositionX={0}
                initialPositionY={0}
                minScale={0.3}
                maxScale={2}>
              <TransformComponent className="containerfoo">
              <div className="containerfoo">
                {gridItems.map(rowItem => {
                  return <div className="GridRow">{rowItem}</div>;
                })}
              </div>
              </TransformComponent>
        </TransformWrapper>
      </div>
    );
```

CSS:

```
.artContainer{
  height: 85vh;
  max-height: 85vh;
  min-height: 85vw;

  width: 85vw;
  max-width: 85vw;
  min-width: 85vw;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

.containerfoo{
  height: 85vh;
  max-height: 85vh;
  min-height: 85vw;
  
  width: 85vw;
  max-width: 85vw;
  min-width: 85vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-color: red;
```

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox and share the link to make it easier to test your code? Are there any css styles for the `body` and `html` ?